Curl list of links and save files according to URL hierarchy
From the first API call, a JSON response is returned which includes a bunch of links. I want to curl each link, and download the file to a location based on the last 3 path segments.
For example, if the URL is https://data.ninjakiwi.com/btd6/races/The_Olympics_lzlqex8k/metadata, then I want to download the file to races/The_Olympics_lzlqex8k/metadata.json.  Apparently cut cannot handle indexing from the end, so I've hardcoded the number of slashes (including 2 in https://) to skip. I came up with an example command. Is there a more elegant way to write this? xargs has showed me this is probably possible without a loop and less subshell usage.
for url in $(curl https://data.ninjakiwi.com/btd6/races | jq -r '.body [] | .leaderboard, .metadata'); do         
echo $url; curl --create-dirs -o $(echo $url | cut -d/ -f5-).json $url; done


Re cut indexing from the end: Try setting a base='https://data.ninjakiwi.com/btd6', then use curl "$base/races", and later curl --create-dirs -o "${url#$base/}.json" "$url".

Interesting bash string functions I've neverused before. Is there a coreutil that can return the last 3 parts of a path?

If you want to stick to cut, rev the string, cut the first three parts, and rev back the result. But I don't see any advantage in doing so.

I saw the rev trick in another post. It's really ugly for something cut should support.

You can always write your own function that provides for it.

Regarding Is there a coreutil that can return the last 3 parts of a path? - yes, sed, awk, and grep -o could all do that.

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

@EdMorton is that a legitimate close reason? What I'm asking about cannot be fixed by shellcheck suggestions

@awr yes because you're making those of us reading your script have to wade through issues that shellcheck could have told you about and you could have fixed wondering for each issue what impact it might be having and how it might contribute to your problem. Always just clean up what you can on your own before asking anyone else to help you with your code to make it as fast and easy as possible for as many people as possible to help you so you stand the best chance of quickly getting the best solution to your problem.

You don't need a loop. This should  work:
curl https://data.ninjakiwi.com/btd6/races |
jq -r '.body[] | .leaderboard, .metadata | "url = "+., "output = "+((./"/")[-3:] | join("/"))+".json"' |
curl -Z -K - --create-dirs


That is clever. I did not know jq could do string splitting and joining like this. I didn't consider parallel, and I knew about -K but never considered jq could serve the arguments on a platter. You've showed me a lot and SO always has something new to teach me.

@qwr Glad to have helped. Good day

this is awesome

Since each curl option is on its own line, how does curl know to separate options? Is it from encountering a new url= ?

Is there an option to run the output file through jq formatting again? I know this is asking a lot for a program without a loop.
